# Why do linker errors refer to two different versions of glibc?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, systemd

I'm linking an app on Ubuntu 20.04 to libsystemd and getting these errors:

```
libsystemd.so: undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask@GLIBC_2.32'
libsystemd.so: undefined reference to `fstatat64@GLIBC_2.33'
```

Why do they refer to two different versions of glibc? Do I need both versions?